# Key and Count optimisation

Tags: xslt

is it valuable (memory,cpu,time) to do this :

```
<xsl:variable name="node" select="key('mykey',category)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="count($node[value/text() = 10.0])"/>
<xsl:value-of select="count($node[value/text() = 5.0])"/>
<xsl:value-of select="count($node[value/text() = 0.0])"/>
```

instead of :

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(key('mykey',category)[value/text() = 10.0])"/>
<xsl:value-of select="count(key('mykey',category)[value/text() = 5.0])"/>
<xsl:value-of select="count(key('mykey',category)[value/text() = 0.0])"/>
```

or another way ??

Answer (score 0):

It might make a small difference, but probably not significant. But the answer to a performance question is always (a) it depends what processor you are using, and (b) measure it to find out.

I would suggest using `[value=0.0]` rather than `[value/text()=0.0]`. Using /text() is a bad habit that seems to be coming in increasingly from the XQuery world. It usually gives the same answer, unless your data contains comments or inline elements or non-normalized adjacent text nodes. Omitting the /text() makes your query shorter and more robust.